# Day elapsed since today from a given date

Tags: c++, datetime

My function calculates days elapsed from the current date.  Input is fixed.  I will get vector.

Please comment on this.

```
static bool daysElapsed(const std::vector<char>& vec,int& val)
{       
    std::string str(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    char *pos;// whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.
    int l = strtol(str.c_str(),&pos,10); // Its intention we don’t check till which length strtol converted
    if ((errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MAX) || l > INT_MAX)      return false;
    if ((errno == ERANGE && l == LONG_MIN) || l < INT_MIN)      return false;

    int year = l/10000;
    int month = (l%10000)/100;
    int date = l%100;

    struct std::tm a = {0,0,0,date,
        month-1,   //Month (0 – 11; January = 0).
        year-1900  //Year (current year minus 1900).
    }; 
    struct std::tm b;               

    time_t rawtime;
    time (&rawtime);                // Get the current calendar time UTC !-> Do not rely on this time, Convert to local time first
    localtime_s (&b,&rawtime);     
    time_t x = std::mktime(&a);
    time_t y = std::mktime(&b);
    if ( x != (std::time_t)(-1) && y != (std::time_t)(-1) ) // Ensure both time are valid
    {
        double difference = std::difftime(y, x) / (60 * 60 * 24);           
        std::cout << "difference = " << difference << " days" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        return false;

    return true;


}
```

Comment: One thing I notice is that the `vec` parameter can be a `const&` since it's not modified in the function.  Alongside that, `cbegin()` and `cend()` can instead be used for `str`.

Comment: Hi all , I finally dumped this implementation. Rather choose very fast way to calculate.You can convert a date to a Julian day number in O(1). and substracte two. Thanks to this beautiful community .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's weird to take a `std::vector<char>` instead of a `std::string`.  If you must take a `std::vector<char>`, then make two overloaded versions of the function, where the vector variant calls the string variant.

You never use the `val` parameter.  You probably meant to use it to return the computed result?  However, the computed difference is a `double`.

`strtol()` returns a `long`, but you assign it to an `int`.  Then you check if that `int` exceeds `INT_MAX` or is less than `INT_MIN` — which is impossible by definition.  Comparing an `int` with `LONG_MAX` and `LONG_MIN` is similarly nonsensical.  Really, all you want to do is check whether `errno` is non-zero.

You seem to expect the input in YYYYMMDD format, but you don't do any validation other than checking for overflow or underflow.  There are plenty of 8-digit numbers that shouldn't be valid dates.

Unfortunately, the `localtime_s()` function is Windows-only.  POSIX has `localtime_r()`, whose arguments are in the other order, but Windows doesn't support it.  You'll probably need an `#ifdef _WIN32`.

When testing for the validity of `x` and `y`, put the early-return failure case first.  That's just a better pattern for error handling, because the successful case doesn't have to be indented another level.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment , I will revisit implementation

Comment: I updated post after fixing you comment. thanks a lot. Your comments helped a lot. Also i am only writing for windows. Input format is fixed.

Comment: I'm glad you got to incorporate some feedback, but please don't abuse the editing feature by modifying the question after the review — it makes it impossible for other users of this site to follow what happened. I've reverted your [revision 6](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/32593/6) back to revision 4. If you want more feedback, please post a separate question that mentions this one.

Comment: By the way, your code is getting really complex after adding validation. The usual way to parse dates and times in C/C++ is to use [strftime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

Comment: Sure i will take care on editing part... Need to learn wow on this site

Answer (score 1):

There is a serious bug in my code:

The function fails if the year is before 1970.  `mktime` handles dates in any timezone from midnight, January 1, 1970, to January 18, 19:14:07, 2038.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246472%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: Whether or not you consider that to be a bug depends on what you define as acceptable input. Date/time calculations tend to get really complicated the more situations you want to support. Do you need to handle the Julian-Gregorian transition? Dates before AD 1? You have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: My requirement is to count age (in number of days) . So perhaps i should at least support 150 year back from current day to be on safer side :). Anyway if i don't get a suitable API i will write my own:)